# How do I specify a lavaan sem model with a single-indicator factor?

Tags: r, lavaan

I would like to run a factor analysis in lavaan with a factor having only one manifest indicator. My problem is that I don't know the correct syntax for the model specification.

What I already do know is that (1) I can set the item-factor loading on the single-indicator-factor to 1 or (2) I have to specify an estimate for the item's error variance which is what I want.

The error variance depends on the item's empirical variance and reliability. I compute the reliability with the Spearman-Brown formula. The original factor has 4 items and the single item version is an "enlargement" to 1/4th. In my example the reliabiliy goes down from .87 to .63 which - I think - understimates the item's reliability.

The item's variance is 1.20 and the error variance is (1 - alpha) * var = (1 - .63) * 1.20 = .45. Now here is the question. Having three other normal factors A, B, C and D1 as the single indicator for D is this the correct model specification:

```
model <- '
   Factor.A =~ A1 + A2 + A3 + A4
   Factor.B =~ B1 + B2 + B3 + B3
   Factor.C =~ C1 + C2
   Factor.D =~ D1
   D1 ~~ 0.45*D1'
Data <- ....
fit <- sem(model, data=Data, estimator="MLM")
```

My particular problem is that every source says that I have to specify the error variance. But lavaan's ~~ operator is to specify a variance. Then the correct coefficient would be D1's estimated alpha times it's variance = .63 * 1.20 = .76.

Answer (score 5):

I hope that you have found an answer at this point, but for the viewers who still want to know how to do this in the `lavaan` package, here's how.

To start I simulated some data:

```
> head(dat)
          A1         A2          A3         A4          B1         B2         B3         C1          C2         D1
1  1.6785322  0.9257293 -0.39660571 -0.5171069  1.47728589  1.3256104 -1.2620390 -0.6492827 -1.10679078  0.8026393
2  1.6168768  1.9164575  1.09444280 -0.3433172 -2.55549628  2.0257767  0.3753301 -2.2027485 -1.74793846 -0.7827619
3 -0.4532672 -1.8770901 -0.01629435 -1.3525647  0.05900466 -1.3453644 -1.3048589  2.1052869 -0.07766467  0.6288775
4  0.6806613  1.2028459 -0.51391579 -1.1764455  1.08308724 -1.7084728 -0.4183617  1.4533609  1.80628226  1.5631844
5  0.2953281 -2.1000532  0.03250903 -1.8928100  0.49891131  0.1838630 -1.1338902 -0.4802558 -0.33459527 -0.5051095
6  2.3563684  1.2439698 -0.85265611  2.1545112 -2.01701660 -0.8861477 -2.3937187 -1.5670614 -0.56750672 -1.8588870
```

Next I built a model with a single indicator for `Factor.D` as described above. In this case the trick is specifying the variance of the observed variable to be equal to 0. This is the same thing as saying that the latent variable will account for all of the variance in the observed variable (i.e., a latent variable with a single indicator).

```
model<-'
Factor.A =~ A1 + A2 + A3 + A4
Factor.B =~ B1 + B2 + B3 + B3
Factor.C =~ C1 + C2
Factor.D =~ D1
D1~~0*D1
'
```

Next, I run the model and obtain my output. To stick with the example above I will use the robust `MLM` estimator, but it isn't required in this situation.

```
> fit<-sem(model, data=dat, estimator = 'MLM')
> 
> summary(fit, fit.measures=T, standardized =T)
lavaan (0.5-22) converged normally after  79 iterations

  Number of observations                           500

  Estimator                                         ML      Robust
  Minimum Function Test Statistic               23.764      24.159
  Degrees of freedom                                30          30
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.783       0.765
  Scaling correction factor                                  0.984
    for the Satorra-Bentler correction

Model test baseline model:

  Minimum Function Test Statistic              990.791     971.021
  Degrees of freedom                                45          45
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000

User model versus baseline model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    1.000       1.000
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       1.010       1.009

  Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                         1.000
  Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                            1.009

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)              -8035.768   -8035.768
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)      -8023.886   -8023.886

  Number of free parameters                         35          35
  Akaike (AIC)                               16141.535   16141.535
  Bayesian (BIC)                             16289.047   16289.047
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (BIC)        16177.954   16177.954

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.000       0.000
  90 Percent Confidence Interval          0.000  0.023       0.000  0.024
  P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          1.000       1.000

  Robust RMSEA                                               0.000
  90 Percent Confidence Interval                             0.000  0.024

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.021       0.021

Parameter Estimates:

  Information                                 Expected
  Standard Errors                           Robust.sem

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  Factor.A =~                                                           
    A1                1.000                               0.892    0.664
    A2                1.003    0.088   11.378    0.000    0.895    0.672
    A3                1.071    0.093   11.500    0.000    0.955    0.718
    A4                1.080    0.091   11.899    0.000    0.963    0.680
  Factor.B =~                                                           
    B1                1.000                               0.961    0.685
    B2                1.081    0.087   12.492    0.000    1.038    0.732
    B3                1.098    0.095   11.597    0.000    1.055    0.744
  Factor.C =~                                                           
    C1                1.000                               0.564    0.409
    C2                2.224    4.074    0.546    0.585    1.254    0.925
  Factor.D =~                                                           
    D1                1.000                               0.973    1.000

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  Factor.A ~~                                                           
    Factor.B          0.059    0.051    1.157    0.247    0.069    0.069
    Factor.C          0.001    0.028    0.049    0.961    0.003    0.003
    Factor.D         -0.015    0.045   -0.332    0.740   -0.017   -0.017
  Factor.B ~~                                                           
    Factor.C          0.033    0.065    0.518    0.605    0.062    0.062
    Factor.D          0.072    0.047    1.520    0.128    0.077    0.077
  Factor.C ~~                                                           
    Factor.D          0.003    0.028    0.108    0.914    0.006    0.006

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .A1               -0.017    0.060   -0.275    0.783   -0.017   -0.012
   .A2               -0.016    0.060   -0.270    0.787   -0.016   -0.012
   .A3               -0.016    0.060   -0.264    0.791   -0.016   -0.012
   .A4               -0.017    0.063   -0.268    0.789   -0.017   -0.012
   .B1                0.063    0.063    1.006    0.314    0.063    0.045
   .B2               -0.003    0.063   -0.041    0.967   -0.003   -0.002
   .B3               -0.044    0.063   -0.690    0.490   -0.044   -0.031
   .C1               -0.054    0.062   -0.874    0.382   -0.054   -0.039
   .C2               -0.012    0.061   -0.198    0.843   -0.012   -0.009
   .D1               -0.006    0.044   -0.135    0.893   -0.006   -0.006
    Factor.A          0.000                               0.000    0.000
    Factor.B          0.000                               0.000    0.000
    Factor.C          0.000                               0.000    0.000
    Factor.D          0.000                               0.000    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .D1                0.000                               0.000    0.000
   .A1                1.010    0.079   12.772    0.000    1.010    0.559
   .A2                0.970    0.081   12.032    0.000    0.970    0.548
   .A3                0.859    0.079   10.857    0.000    0.859    0.485
   .A4                1.077    0.097   11.153    0.000    1.077    0.537
   .B1                1.046    0.091   11.476    0.000    1.046    0.531
   .B2                0.934    0.096    9.753    0.000    0.934    0.464
   .B3                0.895    0.103    8.678    0.000    0.895    0.446
   .C1                1.582    0.593    2.665    0.008    1.582    0.833
   .C2                0.266    2.878    0.092    0.926    0.266    0.145
    Factor.A          0.796    0.099    8.017    0.000    1.000    1.000
    Factor.B          0.923    0.118    7.848    0.000    1.000    1.000
    Factor.C          0.318    0.584    0.544    0.586    1.000    1.000
    Factor.D          0.947    0.059   15.955    0.000    1.000    1.000
```

Note that the variance for Factor.D is the exact same variance as the variance for D1 (using the population formula):

```
> var(dat$D1)*499/500
[1] 0.9468973
```

And there you have it.

Comment: Thanks. the phrase `using the population formula` in the note is really important.

Answer (score 0):

```
 D1 ~~ 0.45*D1
```

This specifies the residual variance. So you should use (1 - alpha) * var.

http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax1.html

Comment: Can you clarify how this goes betond the existing answer? Just giving alink may lead to problems if the link goes dead so can you say what the link says?